# jaspersoft visualize auth undefined url segment

Tags: jasperserver

Why do I see this in console.log (authentication is blocked)

`http://example.com/jasperserver-pro/undefined/require.config.js 404`

when using

```
 visualize(
     {
        server: 'http://example.com/jasperserver-pro/',
        auth: {
           token: authToken,
           preAuth: true,
           tokenName: "pp"
        },
     },
```

Different from the docs my visualize.js is not in /client rather /optimized-scripts, could this be causing an issue? is /client hard coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/client is hardcoded and not on file system. Not obvious and not documented.